# how to add rows into a table when a criteria is not fulfilled

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table of people and where they lived between the years 2005-2010:

```
 Person     Address          From_dt       To_dt           PersonRow
------     -------          ------        -----           ---------
1          known            2005-01-01    2010-12-31      1
2          known            2006-01-01    2007-01-01      1
```

However I want to add in two rows for person 2 so my table becomes:

```
Person     Address          From_dt       To_dt           PersonRow
------     -------          ------        -----           ---------
1          known            2005-01-01    2010-12-31      1
2          unknown          2005-01-01    2005-12-31      1
2          known            2006-01-01    2007-01-01      2
2          unknown          2007-01-02    2010-12-31      3
```

Where the gaps between 2005-2010 are filled in for person 2. even if they have multiple residency the gaps must be filled in. I suppose I am not too interested in the correct dates (notice how the imputed dates are obtained from other residency dates for the same person) as I have been helped out with this already.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Why are you reposting [your own recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293073/fill-in-a-null-cell-with-cell-from-previous-record), especially when you have accepted an answer.  Null are often used to represent "unknown", or you should be able to leverage that answer for what you want here. No?

Comment: this is a different question. i want to add a full new row for anyone who doesn't have residency at any point between the years 2005-2010 and label that residency as unknown. thankfully the issue of addressing how to get the imputed from_dt and to_dt for these imputed rows have been answered in another question, an I indicated as such when I said I am not too interested in getting the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the rows and then in a while loop do something along these line:

```
$prevRow = array();
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($select) ){
    if(count($prevRow)===0){ // first round of loop it has 0 values, so nothing to match
        if($prevRow['To_dt'] !== $fetch['From_dt']){ // check the two rows' dates
            // Please note! This will not work. You will need to add 1 day to the first, or subtract 1 day from the 2nd value!
            // Insert a row "unknown" with the two values from the above if-statement
        }
    }
    $prevRow = $fetch;// save so next round we can compare
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I only have SQL DB2 in my work environment. but I can see that otherwise your answer would eb a good option.